# select method in BeautifulSoup not able to select attribute value with white space

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

```
city = soup.select('a[href="/city/london d12"]')
```

The above code got a error message:

> ValueError: Unsupported or invalid CSS selector: "a[href=/city/london"

I am wondering if there is a workaround or a alternative to beautiful soup?

```
<a title="London" href="/city/london d12">london</a>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to *enclose the attribute value into double quotes*:

```
a[href="/city/london d12"]
```

Though, it appears that this particular selector is identified as "invalid" by `BeautifulSoup`. This is because [`BeautifulSoup` supports only basic CSS selectors](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

> This is all a convenience for users who know the CSS selector syntax.
>   You can do all this stuff with the Beautiful Soup API. And if CSS
>   selectors are all you need, you might as well use lxml directly: it’s
>   a lot faster, and it supports more CSS selectors. But this lets you
>   combine simple CSS selectors with the Beautiful Soup API.

Let's follow the advise and use [`lxml`+`cssselect`](http://lxml.de/cssselect.html) directly:

```
>>> from lxml.cssselect import CSSSelector
>>> from lxml.etree import fromstring
>>> 
>>> sel = CSSSelector('a[href="/city/london d12"]')
>>>
>>> tree = fromstring('<a title="London" href="/city/london d12">london</a>')
>>> sel(tree)
[<Element a at 0x100dad878>]
```

---

You can also use *partial attribute matching*:

```
soup.select('a[href*=london]')  # contains "london"
soup.select('a[href$=d12]')  # ends with "d12"
soup.select('a[href^=/city/london]')  # starts with "city/london"
```

Comment: sorry, I forgot to enclose the attribute value in the post, but it is enclosed in my code. The problem persists

Comment: Thank you very much.Actually I have used variable to replace the actually value `city = soup.select('a[href=%s]'%cityurl)` and `cityurl = "/city/london d12"`  My code iterate through a list of cityurl to get the text node of the specified element

Comment: @XuzhengWang and, btw, you can also use `find_all()` here: `find_all("a", href="/city/london d12")`.